# R - dcast or transpose

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to take the following small sample of data:

```
IndID  J2015  E2015  Area
1      10     5      DC
2      15     7      DC
3      20     10     DC
```

Then use `reshape` or `reshape2` to transform it into the following format:

```
Area  1_J2015  1_E2015  2_J2015  2_E2015  3_J2015  3_E2015
DC    10       5        15       7        20       10
```

I will be doing this over a few million rows of data, however I cannot figure out the correct formula to perform this, part of me believes this needs to be done in two or more steps.

I have tried various formats of the `dcast` function in the `reshape` package:

```
df <- dcast(AreaID + J2015 + E2015 ~ IndID, data = data)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could do `reshape(df, idvar = "Area", timevar = "IndID", direction = "wide")` or `library(data.table) ; dcast(setDT(df), Area ~ IndID, value.var = c("J2015", "E2015"))`

Comment: That works, just need to tweak it for my actual data. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First melt it and then dcast it like this:

```
library(reshape2)

m <- melt(data, id.var = c("IndID", "Area"))
dcast(m, Area ~ IndID + variable)
```

giving:

```
  Area 1_J2015 1_E2015 2_J2015 2_E2015 3_J2015 3_E2015
1   DC      10       5      15       7      20      10
```

or combined into a single command:

```
recast(data, Area ~ IndID + variable, id.var = c("IndID", "Area"))
```